# Kafka redelivery of unacked message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a question regarding kafka consumer:

```
enable.auto.commit=false
max.poll.records=1
auto.offset.reset=latest
group.id="processor-1"
```

---

```
KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer= new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(properties);  
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));  
while(true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String,String> records=consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); 
     for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record: records){  
        logger.info("Value:" +record.value());  
        logger.info("Partition:" + record.partition()+",Offset:"+record.offset());
        //consumer.commitSync();  
    }   
}
```

As you can see auto commit is off and we are not acking the record, can you please tell me after what time we can have the same message. how it will behave if multiple consumer in same group, like message 'A' is read by consumer-1 but did not acked then when the same message can be delivered to consumer-2

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the same messages when this JVM process restarts since you are not committing any offsets.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I have missed to put the consumer group name, edited it now. So the message will come with the poll when consumer restart or group re-blanching take place

Comment: Assuming you're calling `consumer.subscribe` before the loop, yes. Try it for yourself

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, It is behaving like this only. I am looking for something like ack dead line in google pub-sub or Delivery Acknowledgement Timeout in RabitMQ. Is there any way to have that, like if there is a single consumer and got one message, if it does not ack let say within 10 second then will receive the same message

Comment: Consumer will never re-read the same event unless you explicitly call `seek` , or do not commit the offset and a rebalance happens. Kafka is not the same as either of those queues since they have messages removed from the server when consumed